# Make $kt^2+(3k+1)t+4k+1$ constant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find $k$ such that $kt^2+(3k+1)t+4k+1=0$ is an identity (i.e. true for all $t$).

E.g. $k=t+1$ doesn't work since you end up with a third degree polynomial in $t$ which determines $t$, making $t$ constant, so it isn't true for all $t$. Similarly $k=f(t)$ where $f$ is a polynomial doesn't work for the same reasons.

So we probably need $k=f(t,u)$ where $u$ is a variable.

Is it possible? Thanks.

EDIT: Is it possible to do this while making $k\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$? (i.e. a polynomial with integer coefficients)

Comment: And do correct your title or your body - they have different constants for the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Just solve for $k$ to get $$k = -\frac{t+1}{t^2+3t+4}$$

Comment: @Ark  In this case  the only possibility is shown above, and depending on the value of $t$, we will have $k \in \approx [ -0.26, 0.55] $ taking all real values in that interval.

Comment: @Ark I answered the problem in the body of your post. He answered the problem which was in your title.  That's the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
$$k=\frac{-t-1}{t^2+3t+4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: First, solve for $k$ to get
$$
k=-(t+1)\frac{1}{t^3+3t+4}\cdot
$$
To write the above as polynomial in $t$ (with infinite order), find $a$ and $b$ such that $t^3+3t+4=(t-a)(t-b)$ (in this case $a$ and $b$ are complex). Then
$$
\frac{1}{t^2+3t+4}=\frac{1}{(t-a)(t-b)}=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\frac{a^{-1}}{1-t a^{-1}}-\frac{b^{-1}}{1-tb^{-1}}\right)
$$
from which the $n$-th order term of $(t^2+3t+4)^{-1}$ is
$$
c_n\equiv\frac{1}{b-a}(a^{-(n+1)}-b^{-(n+1)})
$$
which is a real (actually rational) number for all $n\geq -1$.  Then for $n\geq 0$, the $n$-th order term for $k$ is
$$
d_n\equiv-(c_n+c_{n-1}),\quad n\geq 0.
$$
Of course, $d_n$'s obtained this way agree with the Taylor expansion on $k(t)$ around $t=0$.